# Why does the Nuclear fusion rate decrease with temperature after a point?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

[image]

According to here the Fusion rate for D-T peaks at a little under 1E9 Kelvin and decreases afterwards. Why is this? Why does the rate stop increasing?

Comment: The fusion cross section is a function of energy, and has a maximum vs energy. Going to higher energy decreases the cross section. Now, a given temperature has a wide range of energies inside it, but the principle still applies.

Comment: In order to fuse, the two particles must shed energy after colliding, e.g. by emitting a neutron. I imagine above a certain temperature this becomes harder to do because the average particle has so much energy.  And the fused product can be easily broken apart again by a collision. Kind of like why right after the Big Bang it took some finite time for H or D or T nuclei to form in the first place. Before that it was (presumably) quark/gluon plasma due to the extreme temperature

Answer (score 2):

The D-T fusion cross section varies with the energy in the center-of-mass frame of the two particles. Equivalently this can be measured by accelerating one (usually D) into a target of the other (usually T).Various cross sections are shown at [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Fusion-cross-sections-for-various-fusion-reaction-versus-ion-temperature-The-DT-fusion_fig2_347530668) (chosen for the nice colors):

[image: D-T fusion cross section from https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Fusion-cross-sections-for-various-fusion-reaction-versus-ion-temperature-The-DT-fusion_fig2_347530668]

The D-T reaction, in the center of mass frame, has a strong energy dependence (attributed to energy levels in the He-5 compound nucleus, but that is another story) with a maximum near 64keV. Below 20keV and above 300keV the cross section is down by an order of magnitude from the maximum.

Looking at it as a function of temperature hides this key point. Using temperature only one has a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of D and T energies, and combining those into a center-of-mass energy for each collision creates a much broader spread of effective cross section vs temperature. Even then, note that the peak in your curve holds to the ~60keV maximum (top axis labeling) - it is there that it is most probable to get center-of-mass energies corresponding to the peak in the cross section.

Temperatures that are higher than, or lower than, that energy result in energy distributions where the collisions will be less and less likely to have center-of-mass energies at the peak on the cross section curve, so the overall reaction rate will decrease.

Comment: And perhaps worth pointing out that the cross section dependancy with energy is basically that they just fly right by each other when they are moving too fast. The reaction times are short, but not zero.